# combineLatest doesn't wait for observable to emit value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 2 services which both have a observable, and a component that *should* get the last emitted value of both observables but the `combineLast` already fires when 1 observable changes, not both:

```js
export class CreateSessionComponent {
  constructor(
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    combineLatest([this.userService.user$, this.sessionService.session$])
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => console.log(data),
      });
  }

  public createUserAndSession(): void {
    this.sessionService.createSession();
    this.userService.createUser();
  }
}
```

```js
export class UserService {
  private userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any | null>(null);
  public user$ = this.userSubject.asObservable();

  public createUser(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.userSubject.next(`User ${Math.random()} `);
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

```js
export class SessionService {
  private sessionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any | null>(null);
  public session$ = this.sessionSubject.asObservable();

  public createSession(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.sessionSubject.next(`Session ${Math.random()} `);
    }, 2500);
  }
}
```

When the function is called I get a value in the `combineLatest()` at both 2500ms and 5000ms.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-g435xp

Comment: The first emission to `combineLatest` comes from your `BehaviorSubject`s so it's behaving correctly. Maybe you want to skip the inital value with `skip(1)` or maybe you don't need to use `BehaviorSubject` and use `ReplaySubject` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`combineLatest` works on the principle: `When any observable emits a value, emit the last emitted value from each.`

If you want to wait for both of your observables to emit the values, you should use `zip` instead of `combineLatest`, I've modified your below `create-session.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { zip } from 'rxjs';
import { SessionService } from '../session.service';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-session',
  templateUrl: './create-session.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-session.component.css'],
})
export class CreateSessionComponent {
  constructor(
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    zip(this.userService.user$, this.sessionService.session$)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => console.log(data),
      });
  }

  public createUserAndSession(): void {
    this.sessionService.createSession();
    this.userService.createUser();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great! I haven't checked all operators yet.

Answer (score -1):

You want to filter out null values so that it only emits when both observables have a value

```
combineLatest([this.userService.user$, this.sessionService.session$]).pipe(
  filter(([user, session]) => user !== null && session !== null)
)
```

This will stop it emitting if either is null, then in `createUser` and `createSession` make sure to set them to null before firing the observable.